# How to get records from the database that wasn't created in the dates range in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-relations

I have a function where I can get all sell records where between dates. Here is the function:

```
private function getSoldsBetweenDates($days, $user, $filter_by)
    {
        $date_from = Carbon::now()->subDays($days);
        $date_to = Carbon::now();

        return Inventory::where('inventory.client_id', $user->client_id)
                                ->withCount(["sellRecord as $filter_by"  => function($query) {
                                    $query->select(DB::raw("created_at"))->take(1);
                                }])
                                ->join('inventory_sell_records', 'inventory_sell_records.product_id', '=', 'inventory.id')
                                ->groupBy('inventory_sell_records.product_id')
                                ->whereBetween('inventory_sell_records.created_at', [$date_from, $date_to])
                                ->paginate(100);
    }
```

But now I need to create a function that will get all records from the database that didn't have any sales between the dates range.

Something like:

```
private function getDidntSellBetweenDates($days, $user, $filter_by)
    {
        What should I do here?
    }
```

How can I get all products that didn't sell between the date range?

Answer (score 2):

You can simple use

```
whereNotBetween
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return Inventory::where('inventory.client_id', $user->client_id)
                                ->withCount(["sellRecord as $filter_by"  => function($query) {
                                    $query->select(DB::raw("created_at"))->take(1);
                                }])
                                ->join('inventory_sell_records', 'inventory_sell_records.product_id', '=', 'inventory.id')
                                ->groupBy('inventory_sell_records.product_id')
                                ->where('inventory_sell_records.created_at','<', $date_from)
                                ->where('inventory_sell_records.created_at','>', $date_to)
                                ->paginate(100);
```